# Find the average height of a pyramid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[Problem Description](http://i.gyazo.com/686b4e9779eb7e9047900d061cbababf.png)
For starters can someone explain to me what the average height of a pyramid is? Does that have to do with its geometric center?

The first thing I did was to calculate the height of pyramid from the formula v = (1/3) * A * H

I got a perpendicular height of 15. I'm not sure where to go from there. I found an example: [Related Material](http://i.gyazo.com/cf1dc3f715dabd02fbe51da7a8b830de.png) [Related Material](http://i.gyazo.com/a2410ab0f3234235b8d39a334255352c.png)
 that seems to be related to what I'm doing, but it goes over my head. Furthermore we haven't covered triple integrals in class, so I'm not sure if that's a different problem entirely.

I tried to follow along with that, but I don't think I am calculating ∫∫∫z dV correctly. When I plug my perpendicular height in, I do not get the same volume as I did using my volume formula.

Edit:
I looked more into finding the centers of mass, and it says the center of mass is 3/4 of the way from the vertex to the mid point of the base. So if I'm interpreting that correctly the height of the center mass is 11.25. I'm very uncertain about that or if it is even equivalent to average height.

Comment: 11.25 is 3/4 of the way from the base to the vertex; you want the other way around.

Comment: Greg, I'm not sure what you mean by the other way around. If you suggesting that instead of apex - center of base I do center of base - apex, my answer still has the same magnitude but a negative value.

Comment: Greg, I'm not sure what you mean by the other way around. If you suggesting that instead of apex - center of base I do center of base - apex, my answer still has the same magnitude but a negative value. If I just think of what was left over I get 3.75 which It hink is correct.

Comment: There is an equation in my book that says to divide the volume by the area  (80/16) to get 5. I am confused between which of these methods is correct.

Comment: If you want to understand this from first principles: the average height of something three-dimensional is the average value of the function $h(x,y)$ that gives the height of the something at the point $(x,y)$. The average value of a continuous function is the integral of that function over its domain (so in this case, a double integral) divided by the area of the domain. You can use that approach here: I suggest restricting yourself, by symmetry, to the triangular domain with corners at (0,0), (4,0), and (2,2).